# Paypal rest api - send invoice issue

Tags: c#, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

i created the draft invoice successfully.  receiving an error when i send the invoice using the sandbox environment

```
{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"9823bcc8a0327","details":[{"issue":"USER_NOT_FOUND","description":"User is not associated with paypal based on invoicer email."}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#errors","method":"GET"}]}
```

i logged into the sandbox environment with the business credentials to see if i could send that way.  i received an error that the sandbox email address needed to be confirmed?

```
To save or send, please confirm your email address (bs@business.example.com) first.
```

fyi: the link in the error is invalid, leads to their default page, so useless

Answer (score 0):

Normally sandbox account emails are already confirmed when you create a new sandbox business account in [the dashboard](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts).

But if one hasn't been confirmed for whatever reason and you need to confirm it in the sandbox environment, note that the sandbox environment never sends any real emails.

Instead log into that sandbox account and go to [the business profile email settings](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email)...

Tere will be a link to confirm it when editing it, or add a new email if necessary. You can resend a confirmation "email" from that edit screen. This "email" message will then show up in the dashboard [Testing Tools -> Sandbox Notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/notifications).

Comment: the resend option may have 'once' been available but is no longer.  changing the business email is the only option which really isnt because you cant change the primary email.

Comment: If you click to edit, there should be a link to confirm this email. You might need to add another email.

Comment: this is not available. the info on the internet that mentions this elusive link is old

Comment: On an account with an email already confirmed, I added another email and there was a link there to confirm it.

Comment: i tried that too, i created another sandbox business account and tried adding and received an error.